# Enable Company mode for all buffers but ESS

Tags: r, emacs, autocomplete, ess

Is there a way to enable Company mode in all buffers...

```
;; enable Company mode in all buffers
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

... except the ESS ones (as, there, Auto-Complete is enabled by default, and in fact much better -- with the quick help, that is documentation appearing in a tooltip)?

Comment: Please try and contact the ESS and Company guys so that the ESS support for completion works not only for Auto-Complete but for Company as well.

Comment: I have opened a new [issue](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/112) for company integration into ESS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize `company-global-modes` accordingly:

```
(setq company-global-modes '(not ESS-MODE))
```

Where `ESS-MODE` is to be replaced with the value of `major-mode` (as in `C-h v major-mode`) in ESS buffers.

Also, note that Company can use completion sources of Auto-Complete, and provides a quick help feature as well (press F1 while the completion popup is shown), so you can also use Company in ESS, if you want.

Comment: No, I did not know about Company using AC sources; and, in particular, Company being able to display a quick help as well. Can you give me a pointer to the needed configuration therefore?  Best regards.